# segmentation fault in c linux but not in windows

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a code to split given Path by the character ":" and there is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parser()
{
    char ** res  = NULL;
    char *  p    = strtok (getenv("PATH"), ":");
    int n_spaces = 0, i;

    /* split string and append tokens to 'res' */

     while (p)
     {
         res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);

         if (res == NULL)
             exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

         res[n_spaces-1] = p;

         p = strtok (NULL, ":");
     }

     /* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

      res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
      res[n_spaces] = 0;

    /* print the result */

      for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces+1); ++i)
          printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, res[i]);

    /* free the memory allocated */

     free (res);
}

int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    parser();
    return 0;
}
```

this code gives me segmentation fault in linux but when a tried to run it on windows , it worked fine !!

Comment: missing `#include <string.h>`. this has the prototype for `strtok`

Comment: and `for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces+1); ++i)` --> `for (i = 0; i < n_spaces; ++i)` or `for (i = 0; res[i]; ++i)`

Comment: Are you running 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Linux?  The missing header noted by @amdixon would therefore cause `strtok()`'s 64-bit pointer return value to be truncated to a 32-bit integer value, as by default functions without a prototype are assumed to return `int`.

Comment: When you invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen. It might give a segfault, it might appear to run OK.

Comment: in Windows the pointer of string returned by `getenv()` is not write protected. and `strtok ` causes segmentation fault if you passe to its first argument a protected string (const). check if in linux `getenv()` returned pointer is not protected

Comment: `res[n_spaces-1] = p;`    in the first iteration of the loop (n_spaces starts as 0 )

Comment: @milevyo I dug a little and found that the pointer returned by getenv() can be in read-only areas according to the C Standard, Sec. 7.20.4.5, The getenv function

Comment: @Magisch i did right now in both windows 10 64bit and ubuntu 15.4 64bit  `strcpy(getenv("path"),"hello world); printf("%s\n",getenv("path"));` and guess what? it printed "Hello world". how it can be explained?

Comment: i have ubuntu64 15.4 on a virtual machine. and the code is working perfectly. so, the only suspected thing is that `getenv()` in your machine is returning a read-only pointer.

Comment: Wether or not that works is irrelevant, as he is invoking undefined behaviour by modifying the getenv() pointer, which is illegal. Additionally he hasn't included <string.h> which means his strtok is not prototyped.

Comment: Thanks all for your help . the problem was forgetting: <string.h>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an include, namely `#include <string.h>` which is responsible for providing the prototype for the `strtok` function you are using. Missing the prototype for this is undefined behaviour, and should not surprise you to not work.

Additionally (credit to @milevyo for pointing this out):

You are not supposed to modify the pointer beeing returned by `getenv()`.

[C Standard, Sec. 7.20.4.5, The getenv function](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~deh25/cmpsc311/Lectures/Environment-Variables/Environment-Variables-2.html)

> Using getenv()
>
> The return value might be aimed at
>
> ```
> a read-only section of memory
> a single buffer whose contents are modified on each call
>     getenv() returns the same value on each call
> a dynamically-allocated buffer that might be reallocated on the next call
> a tightly packed set of character strings with no room for expansion
> ```
>
> Use the returned string before calling getenv() again. Do not modify
>   the returned string.

So by calling `strtok` to a variable assigned a pointer that has been returned from `getenv()` you are invoking additional undefined behaviour.

To correct this, copy the string that the pointer which `getenv()` returned is pointing to into an auxiliary variable with `strdup()`

Comment: Depends on the version of the C standard. Obsolete versions of C allowed implicit function declarations, which in this case would cause the code to go haywire. Newer versions of C will probably give compiler errors.

Comment: @Lundin he is also modifying a pointer returned by the getenv() function, which is prohibited under the c standart `C Standard, Sec. 7.20.4.5, The getenv function`

Comment: @Magisch You are right, but I cannot find the quote you posted in the C standard. The quote in the C standard is different from what you've posted.

Comment: @CoolGuy I have it from here: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~deh25/cmpsc311/Lectures/Environment-Variables/Environment-Variables-2.html    I assumed they would at least quote verbatim from the C Standard, but apparently not. I'll edit in the link, as the reference seems not quite enough.